# Using Struts 2 Assynchronously

Tags: java, web, struts2

I'm considering using Struts 2 to develop a webapp, but I'm currently stuck in one problem.

The webapp I have to develop must provide users the ability to execute commands that runs for long time, such as huge file trasfers. If the user logs off the command (e.g. transfer) must remain being executed in the server. When the user logs back he must see how the execution of the command is being handled or if it has already finished.

Is it possible to acomplish this with struts? How???

As far as I understand the web app architecture, each command executed by a user in a web browser is attached to the session and once he/she logs off and the session is terminated every action requested is dropped, is that right?

Comment: The underlying web framework has nothing to do with this. Jobs would be spun off onto a separate runner, e.g. Spring, throw it into a Rabbit queue, whatever, and their statuses would be made available through (probably) the DB etc.

Comment: Tell us how did you try to accomplish this with Struts or web, also include a *valid code* to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I'm studying the possibilite of using Struts2. I agree with the spring webapp plus independent runner (e.g. Quartz), working as a daemon, it is actually the approach I'm considering. But if my daemon checks the database to, let's suppose every 5 min, then a command executed by the user won't start imediatelly (unless on a lucky situation when it sends the command seconds prior to the database check), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in one of my struts2 project. There were various cases and once a user locks a case for reading that case has to be editable only for that user for the next 5 minutes. Even if he logs out out and logs back in I had to show a time remaining counter. What I did was added a database field caseLocked(timestamp) to the cases table and when the user locks that case a [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduler job starts with a timeout value of 5 minutes after which that database field was put back to null.

So, in your case you can put your task into a job and instead of setting a fixed timeout value you can do polling at regular interval to check the progress of your task and let the user know about the status of the task

Comment: interesting, but just to check if I understood correctly, if my webapp starts a Quartz job, won't it be interrupted if the session ends, since it is being executed through the session?

Comment: No,it wont as long your server is up and running. That is the whole point of using it.